# Cocos2D - How to get a label's value

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can I get the value of Label?
I'm able to set value using [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", val]];
Trying to find the reverse of that, i.e grabbing the string value.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

try `[label label]` or `[label string]`.